# What format does YOLOv2 txt file data use?

Tags: yolo

My YOLOv2Tiny model is drawing bounding boxes in the correct place, however consistently smaller than the object.  This got me wondering if I correctly annotated the images.

Does YOLOv2 use the Pascal VOC .xml format or the same YOLO .txt format that YOLOv4 uses?

Comment: If you are using the Darknet framework, the annotations should be in YOLO format, i.e. one `.txt` file per image, bounding boxes separated by newlines and specified in the format `<class> <cx> <cy> <w> <h>` where `(cx,cy)` is the box center (X is the horizontal axis) and `(w, h)` the size (`w` on the X axis). Coordinates are relative to the image size, i.e. in `0...1`.

Comment: Alright.  That's what I have.  There must be another reason for the poor results.  Thanks